# How to increase root partition on Ubuntu 16.04 server in VM, live

Tags: 16.04, lvm, fdisk

Here is what my disk looks like:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0  256G  0 disk
|-sda1                  8:1    0  976M  0 part /boot
|-sda2                  8:2    0    1K  0 part
`-sda5                  8:5    0   31G  0 part
  |-ubuntu--vg-root   252:0    0 18.2G  0 lvm  /
  |-ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:1    0  3.4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  |-ubuntu--vg-var    252:2    0  4.8G  0 lvm  /var
  `-ubuntu--vg-tmp    252:3    0  4.8G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
sr0                    11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

You can see *sda* is 256G, how can I increase *ubuntu--vg-root* to take advantage of the additional disk space?

Here is what fdisk shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256 GiB, 274877906944 bytes, 536870912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2f0fb28a

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  2000895  1998848  976M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2002942 67106815 65103874   31G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       2002944 67106815 65103872   31G 8e Linux LVM
```

I would love to know how to do this live while the system is running. I have found other similar questions, but none of the answers seem to work for my case.

Comment: No, you can't make partition changes on a live running system. Is your computer UEFI compatible? I ask because your disk looks to be in MBR format, and your LVM disks appear to be in an extended partition. What's on sda1 vs sda5? Probably no easy way to do this. Edit your question with a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: After thinking about this... I'd probably recommend backing up your data, if your computer is UEFI, then lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive), then reinstall a fresh Ubuntu without LVM, and restore your data.

Comment: Actually this is a VM running Ubuntu Server without graphical interface, so no gparted screenshot.

Comment: How would you go about doing it non-live?

Comment: What's the VM engine? Virtualbox? VMWare? What's it used for? Tell me your intentions.

Comment: VMWare. Intention was to get more disk space, so the virtual disk was resized from 32G to 256G, however the OS does not see the additional space.

Comment: You'll have to increase the sda2 extended partition (probably using parted), and then use LVM CLI tools to increase the LVM root partition, all while booted to something like a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. I can't give particulars, as I don't know VMWare.